# How to add category base in wordpress page? How to add category name in wordpress page link?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

> How to add category base in wordpress **page**? How to add category name in wordpress page link?

Answer (score 1):

**To add category base in wordpress page, follow these steps:**
1. Go to Admin panel 
2. Go to Setting > Permalink Settings
3. In Custom structure add this : `/%category%/%postname%/`
4. Done

Answer (score 0):

You have to go on Configuration > Permanent links.

Check last option and put: /%category%/%postname%/

Make sure so your hosting supports rewrite.